# Not able to connect to ARServer

Tags: java, xbmc, remedy

Here is my code:

```
import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARException;
import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARServerUser;
 
public class ARServer {
    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ARServerUser ar = new ARServerUser();
        
        ar.setServer("ServerName");
        ar.setUser("Username");
        ar.setPassword("Password");
        ar.connect();
        ar.login();
   
        try {
            ar.verifyUser();
        } catch (ARException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
   }
}
```

I have created build path for this jar file "ardoc7604_build002.jar" but still i am getting errors like:

> import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARException can not be resolved
>
> import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARServerUser; can not be resolved
>
> ARserver can not be resolved
>
> ARException can not be resolved to a type.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: @all, please mention how to build path for this?? i tried all possible ways, like creating one new folder and giving it as external class folder but still not getting, so please tell me full procedure to build path correctly and importing them into program..

Comment: Check you CLASSPATH. The jar having those classes should be in your CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have put the javadoc jar in your path - you need to use the java api jar instead.

```
arapi7604_build002.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

are you Only Java person or do you understand C# aswell if so I can give you some examples